# File extensions in Slim routes

Tags: php, slim

Why does Slim 404 when I try to add an extension to the route?

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/test', function () {
  echo 'route 1';
});

$app->get('/test.html', function () {
  echo 'route 2';
});

$app->run();
```

http://localhost:8080/test works

http://localhost:8080/test.html throws a 404

Comment: Are you getting result if type `http://localhost:8080/index.php/test.html`?

Comment: That works... Not helpful, but it does work. `http://localhost:8080/(any existing .php file)/test.html` works.

Comment: So, you need `.htaccess` rule to rewrite `index.php` from URL. Do you use such a file?

Comment: No, the 404 is coming from Slim. I can echo random stuff outside the get functions and it shows, so I know the request is being processed, but the route isn't being matched.

Comment: Just tested route `test.html` here and it is working.
Can you edit question and post your `.htaccess` file code?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are running the example using internal PHP webserver. Built-in server will consider request as a static file request if there is a dot in the `SCRIPT_NAME`. It is considered a feature and not a bug. See [PHP bug #61286](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61286) for more info.

Your code should work fine with Apache or other webservers, assuming rewrite rules are set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you! That's frustrating that it will run the file anyway, but leave out data in the $_SERVER array.